# Prevent item in one listview from opening activity in another?

Tags: java, android

I have two listviews, dynamically populated from the same java file. I've set them up to scroll at the same time so that item 1 of list1 is always besides item1 of list2 etc. Unfortunately I've somehow linked the onClick behaviour of the two lists, as when I click on an item in list 2 it opens the correct activity on top of the activity for the corresponding item in list 1. The user doesn't see it until they press back, but it's messing up my stack.

This is my current java code for the two lists:

```
//make listviews scroll simultaneously
    lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(touchSource == null)
                touchSource = v;

            if(v == touchSource) {
                gradeView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    clickSource = v;
                    touchSource = null;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    gradeView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(touchSource == null)
                touchSource = v;

            if(v == touchSource) {
                lv.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    clickSource = v;
                    touchSource = null;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    //make listview items respond to clicks and open relevant activity
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // selected item
            String standard = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StandardInfoActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("standard", standard);
            i.putExtra("subject", subjectId);
            i.putExtra("subjectName", subject);
            i.putExtra("level", level);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    gradeView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddGradeActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("subjectId", subjectId);
            i.putExtra("position", position);
            i.putExtra("level", level);
            i.putExtra("subject", subject);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    //fix inconsistencies in listview scrolling motion
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if(view == clickSource)
                gradeView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, view.getChildAt(0).getTop() + offset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
    });
```

Can you see what I may have done wrong/what I need to add to prevent the lv activity from opening when the user clicks on gradeview?

Edit: and the relevant XML code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/standardList"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3">
            </ListView>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/gradeList"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post your xml code

Comment: Why do you call `finish()` method?

Comment: @UmangBurman just done so

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi because I want to remove this activity from the stack. That is working fine, it's the activity opening when I don't want it to that's messing with the stack.